# MVC Async Repository Pattern Doesnt Go Back to the Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and I am trying to create an app using a Repository Service Pattern, I tried my best to follow some tutorials but right now I dont know what's wrong or what ARE wrong in my implementation because I feel there's something wrong though there aren't any errors when building.

**my controller**

```
  public async Task<JsonResult> Create(string LocationName)
    {
        Location location = new Location
        {
            LocationName = LocationName
        };
        await _LocationService.InsertAsync(location);
        var result = await _LocationService.GetAllAsync();
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This controller receives a string from an ajax post, string is passed correctly to the entity Location {LocationName = LocationName}. After creating a new object of Location, it is passed down to a LocationService:

**LocationService**

```
public class LocationService : ILocationService
{
    private ILocationRepository _LocationRepository;

    public LocationService(ILocationRepository locationRepository)
    {
        _LocationRepository = locationRepository;
    }

    public async Task InsertAsync(Location entity)
    {
        await _LocationRepository.InsertAsync(entity);
    }

    //other async operations below
```

}

So the object Location reaches my LocationService then it is passed down again to LocationRepository:

**LocationRepository**

```
public class LocationRepository : ILocationRepository
    {
        private DefaultConnection dbContext;
        private DbSet<Location> DbSet;
        public LocationRepository()
        {
            dbContext = new DefaultConnection();
            DbSet = dbContext.Set<Location>();
        }


        public async Task InsertAsync(Location entity)
        {

            DbSet.Add(entity);
            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        #region IDisposable
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (dbContext != null)
                {
                    dbContext.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

The object Location is inserted but after the SaveAsync, it doesnt go back to my controller to perform the rest of the operation.

> Note: Location object is saved in the database, but I need it to go
>   back to my controller to return a JsonResult of all Locations.

**questions**

1. Why is it not getting back to my controller after SaveAsync.
2. What can be improved / what is wrong with my implementation so I can make it better.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: *Why is it not getting back to my controller after SaveAsync.* Did you put a breakpoint on the `return Json..` line? Why do you assume it doesn't return?

Comment: Yes I put a breakpoint at the controller itself and trace where it errors, it stops exactly after save async. any idea why it doesnt return after it completes the insert?

Comment: Are you perhaps using `Task.Result` or `Task.Wait` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Nope, thats everything in my code except for the view part which is just a simple ajax post of a textbox, which expects a JsonResult of new list to update my Knockout viewmodel values.

Comment: Try to create a minimal, reproducible example *that others can run*. E.g., does the same deadlock occur if you replace your database calls with `Task.Delay(2000)`?

Comment: @StephenCleary can this be the cause of my problem, I tried to change my async operations to synchronous, like this: public void InsertAsync(Location entity)
        {

            DbSet.Add(entity);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        } } by removing async, after savechanges its now returning to the controller, i think its the "void" that tells my repository to return without return values, how can I put this "void" behavior in an async operation?

Comment: @super-user: The `async` equivalent of `void` is `Task`. But I don't think that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `ConfigureAwait(false)` on both `dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` and `_LocationRepository.InsertAsync(entity)`?

There's a chance this deadlock is being caused by the async methods on the libraries not being able to run on the ASP.NET context. `ConfigureAway(false)` should make every call run in it's own context.

There's a good explanation on async context [on Stephen's blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) . Check that out to learn more.